# What is `/var/metrics` used for?

Tags: filesystem

As the title says. It doesn't seem to be part of FHS, and I could not find much in google. I'm wondering which applications write there, on which occasions, and for what purposes.

edit: In response to the comments:
I am seeing it on a fresh install of Kubutnu 20.04, while inspecting it from another Linux. I haven't booted it yet. It is listed as `drwxrwsrwt  2 root avahi-autoipd` and is empty at the moment.

<s>I'll run the diagnostics when I boot it, and will update.</s>

**Update:**

- From inside the system, it's listed as `drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie`.
- `sudo dpkg -S /var/metrics` doesn't find anything.
- `sudo lsof +D /var/metrics` returns empty.
- `sudo find /var/metrics -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty file` returns `/var/metrics: setgid, sticky, directory` and nothing else. The folder is empty.

Doesn't look like it's being used yet on my system. It's just there.

Comment: On minimal stock Ubuntu Bionic and Focal servers I do not have a `/var/metrics` directory.  What is the output on your system of `dpkg -S /var/metrics`?  Is there anything in the directory?

Comment: In addition to `dpkg -S /var/metrics`, see if it's in use at the monent: `sudo lsof  +D /var/metrics`.

Comment: And `sudo find /var/metrics -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty file`.

Comment: https://www.linux.org/threads/temporary-files.10817/  *"/var/metrics/ or /var/usermetrics/ contains various numerical data"*.  I honestly don't think that you're going to find much data about the folder(s) as they might be used for compatibility.

Comment: @Terrance That's the only info I could find on that, but it's very vague.

Comment: Like the title in the link I shared, it is with the temporary files in Linux.  Like the folder location says `/var` meaning variable as being for temporary usage like `/tmp`. As the system may need `metrics` for numbers temporary storage, that is where it is going to store that data for the time being.  If I were to guess that it is probably there for when you use `metric` like in networking.  Everything in Linux is a file and needs to go somewhere, so it will probably go to the `/var/metrics` folder for the time being until it is no longer in use.